# Office 365 Online Archive - User has access from Portal, but not Outlook

Tags: microsoft-office-365

One of our users is unable to access an online archive as part of a mailbox in Office365. I have checked their permissions and can confirm that they have both FullAccess to the top level of the mailbox and owner permission to the archive folder mailboxname:\archive.

They can access the archive from the online version of Outlook, but when accessed from the Outlook client it is not visible. Just the top level mailbox. I have tried removing and re-adding the mailbox, but it is still the same.

The client version they have is "Office 365 ProPlus - version 1908 (Build 11929.20838)".